# Get names of Online users connected to a Server

Tags: asp.net, signalr, global-asax

I am new to asp.net. I have gone through this [**`link`**](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-show-number-of-online-users-visitors-for-ASP-NET-website.aspx) which has shown how to count the online users connected to a server using asp.net. (*which is working when I tried*)

My question is: What should I change in that code (Global.asax) so that It shows all the names of the connected users instead of counting them.

I created a chat application which stores the name of the connected user in a variable `chatUsername` in `js` file as shown below:

**js file**

```
   var chatUsername = window.prompt("Enter Username:", "");
   //
   chat.client.addMessage =  //Function
   //
   chat.server.send(chatUsername);
```

**.aspx.cs file**

```
//Using SignalR (I think this doesnt matter)
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Send(string from)
    {
        // Call the addMessage method on all clients    
        Clients.All.addMessage(from);
    }
}
```

You can find my complete code **[here](https://github.com/venkateshwar/SignalR-Chat-application)**

EDIT: Please provide a simple example related only to `asp.net` or `signalr` (no other technologies like MVC)

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: following code refers to SignalR v0.5, not the latest 1.0Alpha2, but I believe the reasoning is the same

To do this you need to add several steps to your SignalR connection process, both in the server and in the client:

on the server side:

1. on application start-up, for example, you can instantiate a static in-memory repository (can be a dictionary of  ) that will serve as the user repository to store all currently connected users.
2. In the hub you need to handle the Disconnect event (when a user disconnects, needs to be removed from the user repository as well) and notify all other clients that this user disconnected
3. In the hub you need to add two new methods (the names can be whatever you want) that will help client connect to the system and get the list of currently connected users:

   1. GetConnectedUsers() that just returns a collection of connected users
   2. Joined() where the Hub will create a new User, using the info stored in the round-trip state (the username selected by the client) and the SignalR connection ID, and add the newly created user to the in-memory repository.

on the client side: 
First you need to instantiate the javascript object that relates to your server-side hub

```
var chat = $.connection.chat;
chat.username = chatUsername;
```

Then implements all the functions that will be called by the hub and finally connect to the hub:

```
    // Step 1: Start the connection
    // Step 2: Get all currenlty connected users
    // Step 3: Join to the chat and notify all the clients (me included) that there is a new user connected
    $.connection.hub.start()
                .done(function () {
                    chat.getConnectedUsers()
                                .done(/*display your contacts*/);
                                    });
                                }).done(function () {
                                    chat.joined();
                                });
                });
});
```

If you are asking why we need to add a stage like "chat.joined()" is because in the method on the Hub that is handling the connection event, the round-trip state is not yet available, so the hub cannot retrieve the username chosen by the user.

Anyway I made a blog post to show more in detail how to create a basic SignalR chat web application using Asp.Net MVC, and it is available at:
http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/chatr-just-another-chat-application-using-signalr/

In the post you will also find a link to the github repository where the source is published.
I hope this helps.

Valerio

Comment: I am new to asp.net.. Can you please explain it clearly.. I have gone through the link you provided. But the link follows MVC Concept which is not allowed for me to go with as a trainee..

Comment: Hello, I replied on my blog as well. All you need to understand is that in your javascript code you need to create an object that is linked against your server side Hub (through $.connection.chat line of code), then you need to assign a round trip state to this object (the username of the user, for example), implement all the callbacks that the Hub will be able to invoke from the server, and finally connect to the server via the block of code shown above ($.connection.hub.start().done(....)...); On the server, your Hub will implement getConnectedUsers and Joined(),that's all!

Comment: Oops I dont know that you both are same :).. Anyway I cant go with the link because it is based on MVC which is not allowed for me to go with. I will concern the above comment and try to solve it.. Thank you for reply.

Comment: As I said you don't need the MVC stuff in that link. You basically need to take a look at the getConnectedUsers and Joined methods implemented in the Hub and the javascript portion of the code. The rest is up to you :)

Comment: Let me know if you have more specific questions about it.

Comment: ya sure.. presently I have more doubts which I think I can cover by going through basics.. :D

Comment: Oops yes.. I modified it very much.. Now I am getting two errors(Line:47 and Line: 55) in jquery file.. [`Please check here`](https://gist.github.com/4232310). I mentioned the two errors in middle of the code as comments. and here is the [`Chat class file`](https://gist.github.com/4232291)(for reference, if you need to)

Comment: chat.server.GetConnectedUsers(): you need to use lowercase style, so chat.server.getConnectedUsers() (see my example above)

The other error is due to too many and wrong }); });   (again, see my example above)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you are using [Signal-R](http://signalr.net/) - so try tracking state of online users (i.e. connected clients) in java-script itself. Use `Connected/Disconnected/Reconnected` server side events to broadcast to all clients - from [documentation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs):

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return Clients.All.joined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        return Clients.All.leave(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        return Clients.All.rejoined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

A global server side store (for example - a static dictionary) can be used to store state against the connection id - that way, this dictionary can give you users for needed connection ids. For example,

```
// dis-claimer: untested code - just to give the idea/hint/outline
public class Chat : Hub
{
    // change to use Concurrent Dictionary (or do thread-safe access)
    static Dictionary<string, User> _users = new Dictionary<string, User>()

    // call from client when it goes online
    public void Join(string name)
    {
       var connId = this.Context.ConnectionId;
       __users.Add(connId, new User(connId, name));
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return Clients.All.joined(_users[Context.ConnectionId], DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        var user = _users[Context.ConnectionId];
        _users.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        return Clients.All.leave(user, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
       return _users.Values.ToList()
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 Hey I understand what you are trying to say.. This will store the values in server side.. how to show them in client pages then?

Comment: VS is showing red scribbles to `User` Error --> `The type or namespace name 'User' could not be found`

Comment: @Mr_Green, User would be a custom class - create as per your needs!

Comment: @Mr_Green, on different note, see this sample chat app using Signal-R - IMO, it may help in many ways: http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/chatr-just-another-chat-application-using-signalr/

Comment: Can you please give some sample example how the class `User` should be.. I have gone through the link.. But as I am new cant understand it.

Comment: As a trainee I am not allowed to use MVC architecture(the link follows MVC pattern). Please explain it clearly..

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you :-

```
   void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        Application["OnlineUsers"] = 0;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
     }
      //First check if it is Authenticated request:-
      void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
      list.Add(User.Identity.Name);
       //your rest of code .......
     }
```

list will return you all the username who are online :-

Comment: No effect to the page..  There seems to be two problems in your code.. 1) `list` has been filled but not showed anywhere. 2) `chatUsername` variable of `js file`, which stores usernames, has not mentioned in your code. (I maybe wrong..)

Comment: 1)i have just showed you how to proceed not the full code 2)i do not know how you are passing the JS variable to the server.3) how you have planned to show the username (as table structure,comma separated string or any other shceme)???