# Retrieve names of Online users connected to a Server

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I asked this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13678493/1577396) before which has got a very good response. But as I am new to asp.net (and jquery) cant understand how the program is flowing.

Summary:

> I have created a Basic chat application. Now I am trying to add a advanced function like whenever a user is online (connected to a server), the server should show or broadcast the available online user's username to all the users connected to that server.

By referring the responses to the previous question ([s0nica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13683098/1577396) and [VinayC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13679140/1577396)), I modified my `class` file and `jquery` file, which are giving errors as shown in the below links. (I think I am very close)

> [**Chat.cs**](https://gist.github.com/4223491)   (*Two errors, I mentioned errors in between code comments*)
>      [**file.js**](https://gist.github.com/4223598)   (*Working fine, refer it if you need to*)

Please have a look to the above files and assist me.

PS: In the previous post, I was thinking that if I change the Global.asax code, my problem will be solved.. which I realized later as wrong..

Comment: In your `User` class there is a constructor that takes two arguments. And hence a  default constructor is not generated. You are trying to use the default constructor which is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your first error from:**

```
Clients.joins(Context.ConnectionId, Caller.username, DateTime.Now);
```

Shold be:

```
Clients.All.joins(Context.ConnectionId, Clients.Caller.username, DateTime.Now);
```

Other errors associated with it: In your JS file it should be:
Line 15

```
chat.state.username = chatUsername;
```

**Second error:**
The error is exactly as it states, you do not have a toList function off of your dictionary object.  Secondly you can't plainly convert a List or a string directly to a Chat object.

Based on your setup you currently dont have a proper "user" list to return.  Right now you're saving a List to represent an individual user.  You might want to try changing your dictionary object to be something like

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>();
```

Where User is:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
}
```

Then on your Joined function you could just do:

```
public void Joined()
{
    User user = new User 
    { 
        Name = Clients.Caller.username,
        ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId
    };

    _users.TryAdd(user.ConnectionID, user);
    Clients.All.joins(user.ConnectionID, user.Name, DateTime.Now);
}
```

Lastly your GetConnectedUsers would end up(make sure you're 'using System.Linq;'):

```
public List<User> GetConnectedUsers()
{
    return _users.Values.ToList();
}
```

I probably went a little bit overboard but hopefully this helps!

If you need a reference to the change log from SignalR 0.5.3 to 1.0 alpha here's a great post on all of the modifications:
http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/11/11/microsoft-asp-net-signalr.aspx

Comment: I would do that as well, I would just mention that the Dictionary should be static (or well-managed in a higher context) otherwise you will end up with many instances of dictionary with only one user.

Comment: I probably should have also used ConcurrentDictionary, threw this post together rather quickly.

Comment: now you're showing off :D , just kidding, yeah that one is state of the art and elegance at once ;)